# How to add microblogging functionality to my website

Tags: php, statusnet, microblogging, laconica

I have come across [Laconica](http://status.net/), which seems to have all (and possibly, more than) the functionality I want to add to my site. However, unless I am very much mistaken, it is a standalone application, and can't be integrated into an existing website (I stand to be corrected).

Does anyone know of a way in (other than "rolling my own") which I can add microblogging functionality to my PHP website?. It would be great if I could use Laconica, but I haven't seem how (if) this is possible yet.

**[Edit]**

The reasons for this question are as follows (same reasons as for most 'tighter integration' requirements):

- **Look and feel**

I don't like the 'look and feel' of Laconica. It looks distinctly different from all the other pages in my website.

- **Integrated user management**

I want to integrate (i.e. synchronise) user management workflows (e.g. registration etc.) between the microblogging component and my sites' user management, so that users don't need a separate registration to use the micro blogging functionality on the site.

Comment: Can you elaborate on your purpose for setting something like this up? Do you need any custom features/requirements?

Comment: @JimmySawczuk: Two reasons: 1. I don't like the 'look and feel' of Laconica. It looks distinctly different from all the other pages in my website. 2. I want to integrate users (registration etc), so that users dont need a separate registration to use the micro blogging functionality on the site.

Comment: Please don't blank questions. Delete it if you must, but erasing it with a passive-aggressive "no one's bothering to help me" is silly.

Answer (score 0):

[Tumblr](http://tumblr.com) blogs are pretty easy to embed and should be styleable to fit your website.

Answer (score 0):

Laconi.ca/status.net won't allow that without some sort of "rolling my own" approach, since it's designed to be a stand-alone web service.

That being said, the integration would probably be less involved than you might think.  For example, the navigation in status.net could be overridden via a status.net-like plugin.  Same with the registration flow.

In the end, your both using PHP and likely the same database (maybe, maybe not) - so it should be somewhat straightforward to accomplish.

Answer (score 0):

I had this same issue and found no solutions, so I built my own, http://www.collabinate.com.  From your description it sounds like it would meet your requirements.